# file_get_contents post json returns empty string

Tags: php, json, post, file-get-contents

I got following snippet of code for sending json code to my remote server:

```
    public static function report() {
    $data = json_encode(self::getStats());

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json' . "\r\n"
            . 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents(self::$report_url, false, $context);
    if ($result === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And, on remote server (where I receive the data) I got following code:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request, true);

var_dump($data);
```

However, the output is NULL or empty string.

This line returns empty string:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Function self::getStats() returns correct array, I tested. So it should't be NULL?

Asking for help.

Comment: That's a lot of code at the end that could be replaced with `return $result` instead of the needlessly specific `if ($result === false)`.

Comment: I don't think so. Cause $result can be also string. So doing `return $result` would return string. And I need a boolean.

Comment: Then `return !!$result` which forces it to be a boolean regardless of its original value. Keep in mind booleans in PHP are pretty weak anyway, they're not as rigidly defined as they are in other languages. `0` and `1` are just as good as `true` and `false`. Internally `false` is often considered to be equlivalent to `''`, an empty string, which makes being overly specific a bit pointless most of the time.

Comment: Or `return $result !== false` right? Thanks anyway, I will do this.

Comment: Yeah, something like that is better than calling `if` on a boolean and returning a boolean that's the same boolean you're comparing to.